# How to handle PowerBI workspace and OneDrive file sync when user quits?

Tags: powerbi, onedrive

Assume PersonA has uploaded a power bi (.pbix) file to a folder in OneDrive.

In Power BI workspace, this report has been added to the workspace by linking it to the above OneDrive file.

Subsequently if PersonA leaves the organization, then the OneDrive file will move to recycle bin and the Power BI workspace report will fail to load. Is there any solution for this? How to handle workspace and OneDrive file sync when user quits?

Comment: The manager can take over the users OneDrive files for a few weeks after their departure. You can check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/get-access-to-and-back-up-a-former-user-s-data?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Assuming the manager had uploaded the files and he quits, I have tested that it breaks the sync (since the onedrive file no longer exists), but the report itself is intact in the Power BI workspace (tested this by deleting the .pbix file from OneDrive). So I assume we loose the onedrive file and its version history, but the file is still present in Power BI workspace and can be downloaded (which is the latest version).